# SQL server inner join not returning Description

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

Looking for some help trying to get some information out of my point of sale db. It is a MS Sql 13.0.4001.0 database

I have two tables. A "stock" table and a "stock UDF" table. They look a little like this:

The Stock Table lets call "ST" and the Stock UDF table "SU"

Stock Table has the following columns

```
SKU, Description, UDF1 ID, UDF2 ID,UDF3 ID,UDF4 ID
```

The Stock UDF table has the following columns

```
ID, Description
```

I want to create a query that returns a record but instead of the ID under the UDF1 ID column I want to get the description from the SU table.

A sample record in the ST currently looks like this

```
SKU, Description, UDF1 ID, UDF2 ID,UDF3 ID,UDF4 ID
1000   Orange        2         1     3       Null
```

The SU table looks like this

```
ID, Description
1   Fruit
2   Salads
3   Desserts
4   Vegetables
5   Raw
6   Cooked
```

I want to create a query that returns the following

```
 SKU   Description   UDF1     UDF2    UDF3    UDF4
1000    Oranges     Salads   Fruit  Desserts
```

Not sure how to do the inner join correctly.

Something like this:

```
select st.SKU, st.Description, st.[UDF1 Id], st.[UDF2 Id], st.[UDF3 Id], st.[UDF4 Id]
from [Stock] as st inner join [Stock UDF] as su on st.UDF1 ID = su.ID
```

But doesn't return what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to join to the table with the description multiple times, as follows.  Joins are implicitly `INNER JOIN`, so it's not necessary to state that unless you want to.  Note, however, that in this case you must use a `LEFT OUTER` join type, else where there is no match in the joined table, you will return no rows.

**EDIT**

I've added `COALESCE()` functions so that in the event a `su.Decription` field returns `NULL`, the query will actually output an empty string instead of the `NULL`. `COALESCE()` is a handy function that returns the first non-null value in its set of arguments.

```
SELECT st.SKU
       ,st.Description
       ,COALESCE(su1.Description, '') [UDF1 Desc]
       ,COALESCE(su2.Description, '') [UDF2 Desc]
       ,COALESCE(su3.Description, '') [UDF3 Desc]
       ,COALESCE(su4.Description, '') [UDF4 Desc]
FROM Stock st
    LEFT JOIN [Stock UDF] su1 ON st.UDF1 = su1.ID
    LEFT JOIN [Stock UDF] su2 ON st.UDF2 = su2.ID
    LEFT JOIN [Stock UDF] su3 ON st.UDF3 = su3.ID
    LEFT JOIN [Stock UDF] su4 ON st.UDF4 = su4.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use left joins as you want stock descriptions even if the record is missing. Specifying join or inner join means that the record/field can't be null and return.

```
select
    st.SKU, st.Description,
    st.[UDF1 Id], ISNULL(su1.Description,''),
    st.[UDF2 Id], ISNULL(su2.Description,''),
    st.[UDF3 Id], ISNULL(su3.Description,''),
    st.[UDF4 Id], ISNULL(su4.Description,'')
from [Stock] as st
LEFT join [Stock UDF] as su1 on st.[UDF1 Id] = su1.ID
LEFT join [Stock UDF] as su2 on st.[UDF2 Id] = su2.ID
LEFT join [Stock UDF] as su3 on st.[UDF3 Id] = su3.ID
LEFT join [Stock UDF] as su4 on st.[UDF4 Id] = su4.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are 4 foreign keys in the `[Stock]` table (`UDF1 ID, UDF2 ID,UDF3 ID,UDF4 ID`), you need to join `[Stock UDF]` table 4 times.

```
left join [Stock UDF] as su1 on st.UDF1 ID = su1.ID
left join [Stock UDF] as su2 on st.UDF2 ID = su2.ID
left join [Stock UDF] as su3 on st.UDF3 ID = su3.ID
left join [Stock UDF] as su4 on st.UDF4 ID = su4.ID
```

As there are null values consider using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.